# Load maps into game

Tags: c#, performance, object-oriented, game

I'm currently designing a game using a game engine I created and I'm currently implementing a method that loads maps into my game. The maps are made using [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/), saved as an XML file and are loaded using [TiledSharp](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp).

At the moment, I'm trying to load a map, that contains 1437 'Game Objects' (These are just tiles, as far as tiled is concerned) and currently it takes around 360ms to load. I was just wondering what I can do to load my maps faster.

Here is the code that loads my maps:

```
public void LoadMap(string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading map...");

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    // Import XML data using TiledSharp
    var tmxMap = new TmxMap(path);

    // Lets all the classes variables
    width = tmxMap.Width;
    height = tmxMap.Height;

    tileWidth = tmxMap.TileWidth;
    tileHeight = tmxMap.TileHeight;

    wholeWidth = width * tileWidth;
    wholeHeight = height * tileHeight;

    // Now lets load all the sprite sheets that are used in this map
    var spriteSheets = LoadSpriteSheets(tmxMap);

    // A value that indicates what layer we're drawing to
    int currentLayer = -1;

    foreach (var layer in tmxMap.Layers)
    {
        // Increment a layer foreach layer we're in
        currentLayer++;

        foreach (var tile in layer.Tiles)
        {
            // Get the tiles x, y and global id
            int x = tile.X;
            int y = tile.Y;
            int gid = tile.Gid;

            // Now lets loop through the tilesets in the map
            for (int i = 0; i < tmxMap.Tilesets.Count; i++)
            {
                var tileset = tmxMap.Tilesets[i];

                // This just figures out how many images are in the tileset

                int firstGid = tileset.FirstGid;
                int lastGid = firstGid + (int)tileset.TileCount;


                // Check if the tile we're on is in this tileset, if it isn't continue
                if (!gid.IsWithin(firstGid, lastGid)) continue;

                // Get the regular id, used to get the correct sprite from the sprite sheet
                int id = gid - firstGid;

                // Create a new object, set its position and scale
                var obj = new GameObject();
                obj.Transform.Position = new Vector2f(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight);
                obj.Transform.Scale = new Vector2f(tileWidth, tileHeight);

                // Now lets add a sprite renderer component, and pass it the correct sprite
                var sprite = new Sprite(spriteSheets[i][id], currentLayer, 1.0f);
                var renderer = new SpriteRenderer(sprite);
                obj.AddComponent(renderer);

                // Now lets get the tiles from the tile set, and check if it contains any properties we need to know about
                // Things like if its solid, or has a different depth
                var tiles = tileset.Tiles;

                if (tiles.ContainsKey(id))
                    HandleProperties(obj, tiles[id].Properties);

                // Finally, lets add our game objec to the map
                AddGameObject(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // Dispose of our sprite sheets
    foreach (var sheet in spriteSheets)
        sheet.Bitmap.Dispose();

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Load time: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    if (GameObjects.Contains(Game1.Player)) return;

    AddGameObject(Game1.Player);
}

private void HandleProperties(GameObject obj, PropertyDict properties)
{
    var value = "";

    if (properties.ContainsKey("Solid"))
    {
        value = properties["Solid"];

        if (value == "true")
        {
            // We know we need to add physics and a collider

            var physics = new PhysicsComponent();
            physics.DetectCollisions = true;
            obj.AddComponent(physics);

            var collider = new BoxCollider();
            collider.Size = new Vector2f(tileWidth, tileHeight);
            obj.AddComponent(collider);
        }
    }

    if(properties.ContainsKey("Depth"))
    {
        // Lets set the new depth of the sprite

        value = properties["Depth"];

        int depth = int.Parse(value);

        obj.GetComponentOfType<SpriteRenderer>().Sprite.Depth = depth;
    }
}

private List<SpriteSheet> LoadSpriteSheets(TmxMap tmxMap)
{
    List<SpriteSheet> sheets = new List<SpriteSheet>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tmxMap.Tilesets.Count; i++)
        sheets.Add(new SpriteSheet(tmxMap.Tilesets[i].Image.Source, tmxMap.TileWidth, tmxMap.TileHeight, Color.White));

    return sheets;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any _obvious_ optimizations in your code - it looks good. You'll have to run it with a profiler.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with a profiler. Having said that, there is one easy optimization you can make without a lot of code changes.

Change the following line in *LoadSpriteSheets* from
    `List<SpriteSheet> sheets = new List<SpriteSheet>();`
to
    `List<SpriteSheet> sheets = new List<SpriteSheet>(tmxMap.Tilesets.Count);`

The amount of elements in the list is known in advance so you can avoid the cost of repeatedly resizing the container.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks well written and is easy to read and understand. As t3chb0t stated, you'll have to run a profiler and see where you might make optimizations.

One micro-optimization I found was following: the `Transform` properties of the `GameObject` can be set outside the most inner loop, since the parameters to set them don't change in the inner loop.

```
foreach(var layer ...)
{
    foreach(var tile ...)
    {
        int x = tile.X;
        int y = tile.Y;
        int gid = tile.Gid;

        var obj = new GameObject();
        obj.Transform.Position = new Vector2f(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight);
        obj.Transform.Scale = new Vector2f(tileWidth, tileHeight);

        // Now lets loop through the tilesets in the map
        for (int i = 0; i < tmxMap.Tilesets.Count; i++)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```